# How to write a get response for two different models data in one response sorted by date?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    ...
class B(models.Model):
    ...
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
    ...
```

Both have date field in them. Now I want to write a get response so that I can get both of these model's data from the database sorted by date on the frontend. I have written model serializers with all fields for them.

Now in the get response, I have written something like this:

```
A = A.objects.all()
B = B.objects.all()

aSerializer = A_serializer(A, many=True)
bSerializer = B_serializer(B, many=True)

all = aSerializer.data + bSerializer.data
all = sorted(all, key=lambda item: item['date'],reverse=True)

return Response(all)
```

I think I will not be able to do pagination and other stuff with this. Please let me know if there is any better approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `.union`.

NOTE if `A` and `B` do not share same columns, you need to explicitly pick out shared fields.

```
# Fields to be serialized
shared_fields = ['date', ...]

AB = A.objects.all().values(*shared_fields)\
    .union(B.objects.all().values(*shared_fields))\
    .order_by('date')

# You probably need a new serialize
ab = UnionSerializer(AB, many=True)

return Response(ab.data)
```

--- Edited: SQL View Function ---

Create a view function to union a and b

```
create view myapp_ab_view as
    select 
        date, id as a_id, null as b_id
        from myapp_a
    union select
        date, null as a_id, id as b_id
        from myapp_b;
```

And define corresponding django model

```
class AB(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'myapp_ab_view'
        managed = False
```

And in your view function

```
ab = AB.objects.order_by('date')
```

--- Edit 2: Aliasing ---

```
a = A.objects.all().values(
    'date',
    col1=F('field_m'),
    col2=F('field_n')
)
b = B.objects.all().values(
    'date',
    col1=F('field_x'),
    col2=F('field_y')
)

# This requires field_m and field_x of similar field type,
# such as SlugField and  CharField. So do field_n and field y. 
ab = a.union(b).order_by('date')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A and B do have a common column(date). If I use union and pick up the shared field, I will not be able to have the columns related to their respective objects(different for A and B). If you see my code, I will have an array of json of A and B  objects both.

Comment: You can still get `.union` to work by aliasing all required fields, so that A and B finally share same set of column. Using SQL view function is another option (see edited part of my answer), but I am not sure if it worth the effort.

Comment: Can you please share any code example of how I can still get .union to work by aliasing all required fields? Would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. See edited part 2.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use one to one relationship field between two models and then define serializer linke below

- enter code here

class BasicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = MyModel
fields = '**all**'

class AdvandedSerializer(BasicSerializer):
additional_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

```
def get_additional_field(self, obj):
    return('not important')

class Meta(BasicSerializer.Meta):
    fields = BasicSerializer.Meta.fields + ('additional_field',)`
```